# Are there servers that are oblivious to their own output?

Tags: encryption, public-key, function-evaluation, obfuscation

Suppose there are $n$ parties with public keys $pk_1,...,pk_n$.
Is it possible that a server S constructs an algorithm $A$ so that for some public random nonce $r$ given as input, S computes some "oblivious function" whose output is a tuple of several cipher texts of messages, without knowing the messages?

Namely S computes $A(r)= (E_{pk_1}(y_1),...,E_{pk_n}(y_n))$, but does not know $y_1,...,y_n$ (i.e., for S they seem indistinguishable from random), although S is the one who computed $E_{pk_i}(y_i)$?

Note that S does not get some obfuscated program, but create some program by itself (and the perhaps obfuscates for itself). This seems to me impossible though I am not sure.

Comment: The tag "homomorphic encryption" is missing from your question. Does that mean that you are unaware of that concept? What is, in your case, the input that the server receives?

Comment: It receives only the public keys of the users.

Comment: Anything that's not met by: $E$ is textbook RSA with public key $\mathrm{pk}_i=(n_i,e)$; 4096-bit $n_i$, $e=65537$ and $A(r)=(\underbrace{r,\ldots,r}_{n\text{ terms}})$ ? [update]: we want $n\ll e$, $\log_2{n_i}\ll e$, and that $r$ is random.

Comment: When you encrypt using RSA then you simply compute $m^e\ (mod\ n)$, and so you know m. My question is whether it is possible to create an algorithm that output $E_{pk_i}(m)$, without knowing the actual message m?

Comment: @Doron: no, in my system, the device that computes $A(r)$ does not know the messages, if $r$ is random. They are $y_i=r^{d_i}\bmod n_i$ where $d_i=e^{-1}\bmod\lambda(n)$. I'm not stating this is an answer to the question; I'm proposing that minimal thing to elicit details. Please add them by [editing the question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/101946/edit), rather than in comment.

Comment: Is this within the context of a group chat? You want the server to encrypt a message for everyone in the group, but the sender does not know the public keys of everyone in the group? And for some reason you don't want the server to share all public keys of group members with the recipient, so that the recipient can do the encryptions itself and send the encrypted messages to the server to be passed on to the recipients?

Comment: @grieu You are right. I will edit this

Comment: @knaccc interesting application but no. In fact my end goal is to prove some impossibility result. I want to show that given n users who submit encryption of random values (which can be large), no Turing machine can output n encryptions of distinct values (1,...,n) to the users, without learning them. In general the server can execute multi-key FHE , though it's unclear how to send the users output that are encrypted with different PK. In fact, the paper "Spooky Encryption and its Applications" hints that this is impossible, although it leaves the room for spooky encryptions.